# Correlation failed at signin-oidc after the redirect from the identityserver in production

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openid, .net-5, openiddict

I have an implementation of OpenID cookies authentication, But when I log in from the **IdentityServer** (which is hosted with the same IP but with a different port), and get redirected to the Web-Application.

I get the error as

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
```

Further, the stack trace looks like this:

```
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The redirect URL is in HTTP, not HTTPS. which is in the format as:
`http://some-ip/signin-oidc`

The startup configuration looks like this:

```cs
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie(options =>
  {
      options.LoginPath = "/login";
      options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
      options.SlidingExpiration = false;

  })
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
  {
      options.ClientId = "signal-frontend";
      options.ClientSecret = "signal-frontend-secret";
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
      options.SaveTokens = true;
      options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
      options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
      options.Authority = configuration["IdentityOptions:IdentityUrl"];

      options.Scope.Add("openid");
      options.Scope.Add("email");
      options.Scope.Add("profile");
      options.Scope.Add("roles");
      options.Scope.Add("signal.system.web");

      options.SecurityTokenValidator = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
      {
          // Disable the built-in JWT claims mapping feature.
          InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
      };

      options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
      options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

  });

services.AddOpenIddict()
.AddValidation(options =>
{
    options.SetIssuer(configuration["IdentityOptions:IdentityUrl"]);
    options.AddAudiences("signal_resource");
    options.UseIntrospection()
            .SetClientId("signal_resource")
            .SetClientSecret("secrets");
    options.UseSystemNetHttp();
    options.UseAspNetCore();
});
```

The login controller is implemented as:

```cs
[HttpGet("~/login")]
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

The application runs without problem on the local server. But when it is hosted in the production environment I get the error. I have tried to set the SameSite.None and SameSite.UnSpecified. But the error is the same.

I have checked it in the chrome and edge. There is the same error. I haven't able to verify on the other browser. Chrome is the default browser.

And the app is running in mobile safari browser, in mobile firefox (and some firefox in desktop too). The problem seems so weird. I don't have any clue how to make this work. What is the workaround for this? How to solve the problem?  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use load-balancing and multiple copies of the client application?

If so, the client instance that create the initial authentication request to your identity provider, must also be the same that handles the callback to /signin-oidc

Comment: No, i haven't use the load-balancing. We have hosted the application in AWS EC2 instances.

Comment: We have used the single instances of the client application hosted in the IIS

Comment: Do you get the problem all the time or just after redeployment?

Comment: Everytime on production environment. It is my first deployment and I have got the error.

Comment: how do you deploy it in production? what environment?

Comment: It is in AWS EC2 instances, Windows Enviroment. We use web-deploy method to deploy to the instance.